# perl replace time stamp digits inside string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a problem using perl to replace timestamp on the fly. Inside config.pm, I have a place holder for timestamp:

```
our $PrintableTimeStamp = "20130101_010101";
```

I would like to replace the digits with the current timestamp generated on the fly, i.e.,

```
$current = $year.$mon.$mday."_".hour.$min.$sec; # (e.g., 20131230_153001)
```

I used the following command works,

```
perl -p -i.bak -e s/20130101_010101/$current/g config.pm
```

but not this one below, which I hope can be more generic and flexible

```
perl -p -i.bak -e s/\d{8}_\d{6}/$current/g config.pm
```

Any reason?

Comment: What sets `$current`? At first, I thought it was a shell variable, but you show it constructed using Perl code. Something's not right here. Could you please post a more accurate description of the problem?

Comment: Has figured out my problem. Should be perl -p -i.bak -e s/\\d{8}_\\d{6}/$current/g config.pm.

Comment: Also has found that this particular regex syntax is somehow not working if called under system() call, have to use eval {run \@command...} to make it working correctly. Very tricky.

Comment: @user3147658 Are you really not using quotes for your command line code? I.e. `perl -e ' ... '` (note the single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider binding `=~` and you probably need to group `()` your expected string of numbers in your regex pattern.  Here's an example of a routine I wrote to verify a MAC address is the correct length before I use it in a database query:

```
sub verify { #{{{ pull out the colons, verify char = 12, replace colons
my @newmac;
    foreach my $hostmac (@_) {
    chomp($hostmac);
    if ($hostmac =~ /(?:[A-F0-9]{2}:){5}[A-F0-9]{2}/) {
        push (@newmac,$hostmac);
    } else {
        my $count;
        $hostmac =~ s/\://g; # take out the colons
        if ($hostmac =~ /^.{12}$/ ) { # make sure we have a 12 character string
            $hostmac = sprintf "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s", unpack("(A2)6","\U$hostmac\E");
            push (@newmac, $hostmac);
        } else {
            print "$hostmac\n";
            print colored ("$hostmac should be 12 characters long\n", 'red'); die; # You FAIL!!
        }
    }
}
return $newmac[0] if $#newmac == 1;
return @newmac;
```

}